# unexplained issues utilising fillna()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df;

```
{'country': {640: 'Venezuela, RB', 641: 'Venezuela, RB', 642: 'Venezuela, RB', 643: 'Venezuela, RB', 644: 'Venezuela, RB', 645: 'Venezuela, RB', 646: 'Venezuela, RB', 647: 'Venezuela, RB', 648: 'Venezuela, RB', 649: 'Venezuela, RB'}, 'year': {640: '1995', 641: '1996', 642: '1997', 643: '1998', 644: '1999', 645: '2000', 646: '2001', 647: '2002', 648: '2003', 649: '2004'}, 'Inflation': {640: nan, 641: nan, 642: nan, 643: nan, 644: nan, 645: nan, 646: nan, 647: nan, 648: nan, 649: nan}}
```

Which has many countries, this is the tail, for which Venezuela has many NaN values. I want to replace these with values from another df, which I set the index numbers to match the main df above. It is called df_V

```
{'country': {525: 'Venezuela, RB', 526: 'Venezuela, RB', 527: 'Venezuela, RB', 528: 'Venezuela, RB', 529: 'Venezuela, RB', 530: 'Venezuela, RB', 531: 'Venezuela, RB', 532: 'Venezuela, RB', 533: 'Venezuela, RB', 534: 'Venezuela, RB'}, 'year': {525: 1980, 526: 1981, 527: 1982, 528: 1983, 529: 1984, 530: 1985, 531: 1986, 532: 1987, 533: 1988, 534: 1989}, 'Inflation': {525: 20.94726767651016, 526: 20.588477814454166, 527: 10.163124878901897, 528: 6.642275237205508, 529: 6.920491255381944, 530: 17.043721529702637, 531: 9.95424654983843, 532: 12.824921633483587, 533: 38.2611159060269, 534: 36.431816868877775}}
```

I have tried to fill the NaN with the corresponding values,

I tried the following

```
df_merged = df.set_index(['country','year']).combine_first(df_V.set_index(['country','year'])).reset_index()
df_merged.tail(50)
```

But this just merged it onto the bottom, leaving me with two lots of Venezuela.

I then tried fillna();

```
df['Inflation'] = df['Inflation'].fillna(df_V['Inflation'])
df.tail(25)
```

But the original df was unchanged with all the NaN's inplace. I did the same above for a different country that I wanted to replace the NaN's with from another df, index, column names all the same and it worked. Any idea why it isn't working here? I have checked my NaN's they are all strings.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the indices of the two dataframes don't match up.

You could use `.iloc` to match the dataframes purely by position, or you could match the index of `df_V` to that of `df`. For the latter, for example this should work

```
df_V2 = df_V.set_index(df.index)
df['Inflation'] = df['Inflation'].fillna(df_V['Inflation'])
```

Be aware that this works with your example data. If there are other rows with data in `df_V`, the indices may still not align after the `set_index()` operation. (Which makes sense, considering the data are from different years; they weren't really meant to line up.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It initially did not work, but then I set the indices to match via: ````df_V.index = np.arange(625, 650)```` which made it the same as in the main dataframe, then your suggestion worked, Thanks!